# MariaDB UPDATE queries extremely slow

Tags: mariadb

I have a `user` table, for which UPDATE queries are extremely slow to complete. SELECT queries seem fine.

The DB is MariaDB 10.1.48.

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  active tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  email varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  mobile varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  isMobile_verified enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  device_type enum('0','1','none') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'none' COMMENT '1-Ios,0-Android',
  device_token text,
  password varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  updated datetime NOT NULL,
  updated_by int(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


ALTER TABLE user
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (id),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY email (email),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY mobile (mobile),
  ADD KEY active (active);


ALTER TABLE user
  MODIFY id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Even via PHPMyAdmin or console, a very basic UPDATE query on an indexed column will take 4 to 5 seconds to run. As this is a core table for my application the cumulative effect causes some transactions to run for up to 40 seconds.

There are only c.190K records in the table. Other tables in the DB, including those of similar or larger size, do not seem to be affected.

Is there some issue with the DB version I should upgrade away from, or perhaps a cache problem? Proplem surfaced in the past few months and seems to be getting progressively worse with time. Any help greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Sample UPDATE query, with EXPLAIN output:

```
EXPLAIN UPDATE user SET isMobile_verified = 0 WHERE id = 1;
```

```
+---------+--------+--------+----------+----------+----------+-------+-------+-------------+
| select  | table  | type   |  keys    |   key    | key_len  | ref   | rows  |    Extra    |
+---------+--------+--------+----------+----------+----------+-------+-------+-------------+
| SIMPLE  | user   | range  | PRIMARY  | PRIMARY  |       4  | NULL  |    1  | Using where |
+---------+--------+--------+----------+----------+----------+-------+-------+-------------+
```

Comment: What other traffic is on the DB while you run your update? Is it possible that most time is spent waiting on the necessary locks?

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri No traffic at all when I was testing.

Comment: Can you add an `update` query example, along with the `explain` output?

Comment: @PaulT. Sure; I have added it to the question.

Comment: Thanks for that. Nothing seems out of place to me, but I'll have to think about it a little more. This might also be worth asking over at https://dba.stackexchange.com. Maybe [this answer at dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/281444/significant-query-performance-degradation-over-time-for-only-certain-conditions) could be related as it seems similar to what you've asked here, with a version a little lower than yours.

Comment: @PaulT. Figured it out - Foreign key constraints, specifically from other DBs, targeting the ID column had built up over time. Ran a script to drop them all and the table updates like butter. I'll just have to refactor and that should resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foreign key constraints, specifically from other DBs, targeting the ID column had built up over time. Refactoring to remove those constraints (and allow for their removal!) resolves issue.